# VBA passing argument to parameter in method vs :=

Tags: excel, vba, function, methods, arguments

I learned java and C, now I'm trying to learn VBA for excel, but I'm a bit confused regarding passing arguments to a VBA method

When we pass argument in C, we do:

```
void Foo(int i)
{
    // Do things
}

void Bar()
{
    int temp = 1;
    Foo(temp);
}
```

But in vba, when I use record macro to learn, it gave me this line.

> ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="NewName", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!C8"

If I were to attempt to use the method  `Add` without having the record function i would have typed

> ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add("NewName", "Sheet1!C8")

what confuses me is sometimes we pass argument to method just like java/C, such as:

> Cells(Rows.count, 1)

So when do we use  `:=` , when do we just pass the argument like in java/C?

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251503.aspx

Comment: o this is perfect! I couldnt find this article when i was searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass all requisite arguments along in order, you do not need named arguments (java/C style). If you skip optional arguments (relying on their defaults) or pass arguments along out of their declaration order then you need to name the arguments.

To illustrate this using the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) and [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx):

```
Dim r As Long, c As Long
r = 5
c = 8
'ordered Cells args, first 2 args in Address changes from defaults
Debug.Print Cells(r, c).Address(0, 0)    '<~~ H5
'out-of-order Cells args
Debug.Print Cells(Columnindex:=c, RowIndex:=r).Address(0, 0)    '<~~ still H5
'out-of-order Cells args and only the 4th arg for .Address
Debug.Print Cells(Columnindex:=c, RowIndex:=r).Address(external:=True)    '<~~ [Book2]Sheet3!$H$5
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now

edit: I was trying out one of the example in microsoft.com:

     `Sub PassArgs(strName As String, intAge As Integer, dteBirth As Date)
 Debug.Print strName, intAge, dteBirth
End Sub`

`PassArgs ( "Mary", 29, #2/21/1969#)` 'this gave me an error'
However, if i do `PassArgs "Mary", 29, #2/21/1969# ` 
or `PassArgs strName:="Mary", intAge:=29, dteBirth:=#2/21/1969#` are fine